# How to delete documentation from PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

I just noticed that there is some ancient version of documentation accessible  directly at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim (right at the top, under [Package Documentation](http://packages.python.org/gensim)). I may have tested that feature when first trying PyPi, ages ago.

Now real documentation for my package is maintained elsewhere. I'd like to get rid of that PyPi link and that silly page. Is there a way?

---

So far, I managed to "re-upload" a zip file containing an empty index.html, through the PyPi package admin interface. I thought that would at least provide an empty page to users unfortunate enough to click on the PyPi documentation link. Any way to delete it completely?

Neither "upload nothing" nor "upload an empty zip" work, PyPi checks for a zip and it must contain an index.html file.

Comment: Can't you display a link to the new documentation?

Comment: Can I? That would be perfect. I can't figure out where this `Package Documentation` metadata resides and how to update it.

Comment: 5 Years later... I am wondering if there is a better way than uploading a javascript redirection html document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create a new `index.html` file with a link to the new documentation or even a redirect:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A web page that points a browser to a different page after 2 seconds</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://www.example.com">
        <meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
    </head>
    <body>
        {PACKAGE_NAME}'s documentation is maintained elsewhere.
        You will be redirected to the new documentation within 2 seconds.
        If the browser does not automatically redirect you, you may want to go to <a href="http://www.example.com">the destination</a> manually.
    </body>
</html>
```

Now zip it and go to http://pypi.python.org/pypi. Then login and go to your package's admin page.
There you will find a button to upload the zipped documentation:

[image]

Comment: Thx, the redirect is a nice idea! I'll wait a bit to see if someone knows a direct answer. If not, I'll accept this.

Answer (score 4):

Pypi [recently](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/pull/516) added an option to *destroy* the documentation.

Log into your package and there is now an option to `Destroy Documentation`.

[image]

Comment: Just be patient, in my case it took about 20 seconds to delete and update the main package page.